# bison:Where is yypstate and YYPUSH_MORE defined?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm using flex and bison to develop a calculator. But when I want to make it a push parser, I got the following:

```
"flex" lexer.l  
gcc    -c -o lex.yy.o lex.yy.c  
lexer.l: In function 'main':  
lexer.l:29:2: error: unknown type name 'yypstate'  
lexer.l:29:15: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]  
lexer.l:35:24: error: 'YYPUSH_MORE' undeclared (first use in this function)  
lexer.l:35:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in  
make: *** [lex.yy.o] Error 1
```

And the code is available at https://github.com/dramforever/drcalc (tag `u1-push-parse`). I'm not posting it here because I think it's considered annoying.

PS:Sorry for okay English. Hope you can understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a push parser, you need to specify

```
%define api.pure full
%define api.push-pull push
```

in your bison (.y) file. (Actually, you only need the second one, but the first one is highly recommended. See [the bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Push-Decl.html#Push-Decl).)

That should cause the symbols to be put into the header file generated by bison, if you've requested a header file. To request a header file, include

```
%defines
```

or invoke bison with the `-d` flag.

Of course, you will need to `#include` that header file in any source file which refers to the symbols; in your case, your `flex` input file.

Also, make sure that your `Makefile` specifies that the `bison` header file depends on the `bison` step, and that the `flex` step depends on the `bison` header file. Otherwise, you may find that the build happens in the wrong order.

Comment: Well,I don't think that it's because one of the problems above. Did you check out my code?

Comment: @user1528601 I didn't because there was no branch called variable. However, I just took a look at the branch called push-parse, and it compiled ok for me, aside from the yywrap macro which I had to delete. (use `%option noyywrap` if you don't need yywrap.) So I have no idea why it didn't work for you, aside from maybe bad dependencies in your Makefile.

Comment: @user1528601, oh, and your actions are missing semicolons. They have to be valid C.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for correction. Well did you make or manually compiled the code?

Comment: @user1528601 I did it manually. first bison, then flex, then gcc.

Comment: @user1528601: I looked at your `Makefile` more carefully. You have the rule: `drcalc : lex.yy.o parse.o` but no rule for `parse.o` (the rule you have is for `parse.tab.o`) That will cause `parse.o` to be generated using your system's default rule, which will generate it from parse.y, but probably not with the `-d` flag, and quite possibly in yacc-compatilibility mode. Beyond that, I have no idea what might happen, since I don't know anything about your system, but it's unlikely to work properly.

Comment: Oops, that's a typo! I'll soon check if this is the problem and approve your answer if so. Btw my system is Ubuntu 12.10